# Infinite Scroll on Self-hosted Wordpress

Tags: plugin-jetpack

Trying to move a Wordpress website from Wordpress.com to a self-hosted version.

http://onvegetables.com/

The site automatically had infinite scroll on Wordpress.com and I'm trying to implement that on the self-hosted version.

Is that feature part of the JetPack plugin? If not does WordPress offer a way to simulate that functionality on self-hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetpack does provide the infinite scroll, but unlike other functionality it may require you to modify your theme to support it.

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/).

Comment: Or check out Otto's tut: http://otto42.com/e0